# wxpython message dialog right to left

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, right-to-left, messagedialog

i am using this command, which should switch my layout to RTL but the message dialog is still LTR:

```
 self.SetLayoutDirection(wx.Layout_RightToLeft)
```

message dialog:

```
  FinishMessage=wx.MessageDialog(self, "הבדיקה הסתיימה\r\n התוצאות נמצאות בקובץ אקסל במיקום הקובץ", caption="סיום בדיקת ניחות",style=wx.OK)
```

how do i fix the text will be right to left?

Comment: which os you are trying it on? Which version of {wx}python?

Comment: Windows - wxpython version 4.0.0.2.b2 msw phoenix