# wxpython MessageBox text right to left

Tags: wxpython, messagebox

I am using **wx.Messagebox** and trying to change it to **RTL**:

```
wx.MessageBox(text, title, wx.OK | wx.ICON_EXCLAMATION)
```

How do I transform it to **RTL**? I searched google, but didn't find an answer.

My entire GUI use:

```
self.SetLayoutDirection(wx.Layout_RightToLeft)
```

It's ok except the **messagebox**, how do I change it?

Comment: This question had been already raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246408/wxpython-message-dialog-right-to-left). No answer in 5 years.

Comment: Yes but still it not working and none answer..